# Why react-router redirect gives one less component rendering then when i refresh URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can someone explain me why redirecting with props.history.push('/something') gives me one render less in my component then when I refresh the the same page i am redirecting to? I am asking that cause i am using useRef, and when component rendered two times constant that have useRef stays null, and when i refresh page it gets render three times, and constant isn't null anymore then object i assign it to.

First component:

```
const FirstComponent = (props) => {

    const handleClick = (userId) => {
        props.history.push('/somewhere/${userId}');
     }

    return(
       <TableUsers editUser={handleClick} usersData={props.usersData}></Table>
    )
}
```

TableUsers component:

```
const TableUsers = ({editUser, usersData}) => {

    return(
       <Table>
          {usersData.map(user => <TableRow onClick={() => editUser(user.id)}>{user.name}</TableRow>}
       </Table>
    )
}
```

Second component:

```
const form = useRef(null)
const formProps = form.current

console.log(formProps)

...

<Formik
    ref={form}
...
</Formik>
```

So when i redirect with props.history.push to page with that component i get two renders and formProps stays null, but when i am on that page an i refresh it i get three renders, and fromProps get all props from Formik?

Comment: Is this a typical pattern? Considering that `prop`s must be immutable, I'm willing to bet your issue is trying to push to the history prop

Comment: @Nick i think so, cant figure out something else

Comment: Can you show the component that's passing `history` down to this one?

Comment: @Nick that is prop from react-router it is something like this <ListItem component={NavLink} to="/ads" onClick={toggleDrawer}>, i added more code to be more 
clearer